# jQuery toggleclass Button action to Checkbox action

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, checkbox

Hi I use the code for Wordpress and the theme builder DIVI.
I am a really noob beginner with JS and jQuery.
The code provide a features to have Night Mode when pushing on a button.
I find a custom toggle switch button on Codepen and I like it, and I would love to use it for the code bellow.
This JQuery code it's make for button action "click" but I would love to custom it to react to a "Checkbox".
Is it possible to make a toggleclass with checkbox?

here is the link : [Link off the website](http://www.article10.fr/article10)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Hide the div
jQuery('#rv_button').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();jQuery(".reveal").toggleClass('light dark', 1000);
jQuery('#rv_button').toggleClass('opened closed');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Jim, it's definitely possible to toggle class with checkbox. Could you please share the steps you've taken towards building the React version so we can iterate and work out an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

```
<style>
.light{
  background:red;
}
.dark{
  background:green;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxdav" id="customCheck1"><span class="color_code dark">Checkbox</span>   
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".checkboxdav").on("click", function(e) {
      $(".color_code").toggleClass('light dark');
  });
});
</script>
```